# Difference between df[x], df[[x]], df['x'] , df[['x']] and df.x

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Struggling to understand the difference between the 5 examples in the title. Are some use cases for series vs. data frames? When should one be used over the other? Which are equivalent?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. `df[x]` — index a column using variable `x`. Returns `pd.Series`
2. `df[[x]]` — index/slice a single-column DataFrame using variable `x`. Returns `pd.DataFrame`
3. `df['x']` — index a column named 'x'. Returns `pd.Series`
4. `df[['x']]` — index/slice a single-column DataFrame having only one column named 'x'. Returns `pd.DataFrame`
5. `df.x` — dot accessor notation, equivalent to `df['x']` (there are, however, [limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access) on what `x` can be named if dot notation is to be successfully used). Returns `pd.Series`

With single brackets `[...]` you may only index a single column out as a Series. With double brackets, `[[...]]`, you may select as many columns as you need, and these columns are returned as part of a new DataFrame.

---

**Setup**

```
df
   ID   x
0   0   0
1   1  15
2   2   0
3   3   0
4   4   0
5   5  15

x = 'ID'
```

**Examples**

```
df[x]

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
Name: ID, dtype: int64

type(df[x])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

```
df['x']

0     0
1    15
2     0
3     0
4     0
5    15
Name: x, dtype: int64

type(df['x'])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

```
df[[x]]

   ID
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5

type(df[[x]])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

```
df[['x']]

    x
0   0
1  15
2   0
3   0
4   0
5  15

type(df[['x']])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

```
df.x

0     0
1    15
2     0
3     0
4     0
5    15
Name: x, dtype: int64

type(df.x)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

---

**Further reading**
[Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data)

Comment: Thank you this is super helpful. This question came up for me in the context of: `df[label] = df[label].apply(categorize_label, axis=0)` vs. 
`df.label = df[['label']].apply(categorize_label, axis=0)` where categorize label is just a lambda function. How would I know when would one be appropriate but not the other?

Comment: @user8834780 Slice a series when you need a series, and slice a DataFrame when you need a DataFrame. As for the convention (attribute v/s dict-like) make you're consistent. What to use is a matter of taste, but the attribute/dot access has limitations. By the way, `df[label]` vs `df['label']` is like comparing apples and oranges; semantically they do not mean the same thing (as I've explained above).

Comment: Minor note: this isn't slicing - just indexing.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks! Corrected language.

Comment: I guess my confusion is here that for seemingly same cases: https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/machine-learning-with-the-experts-school-budgets/exploring-the-raw-data?ex=7 at 3:45 and `num_unique_labels = df[LABELS].apply(pd.Series.nunique)`
for https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/machine-learning-with-the-experts-school-budgets/exploring-the-raw-data?ex=10. why does one use df[x] and one df['x']?

Comment: @user8834780 The context isn't the same. `df[['labels']]` and `df[LABELS]` do very different things (LABELS is a list of strings it seems, so `df[LABELS]` is the same as `df[[col1, col2, ...]]`.)

Comment: Ah that makes so much more sense I dont know how I missed that! Thank you

Comment: "With single brackets [...] you may only index a single column out as a Series" - simply not true when you pass in a list of strings.  The VERY FIRST THING to get is that Pandas HAS NO `[[` operator.  The inner pair of `[...]` simply create a Python List object that is then passed into Pandas's `[` operator,

Answer (score 0):

df['label']----single column
df[['label']]----multiple columns
for eg: if 'labels' are independent variables , and 'able' is a target variable, then when plotting it is as df[['labels']] and df['able'].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).