# what’s the difference between df[‘’] and df[[‘’]]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written a function to show elbow to select the optimal value of K of Kmeans.

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
def show_elbow(df):
    distance_list=[]
    K = range(1,9)
    for k in K:
        kmeams=KMeans(n_cluster=k,max_iter=100)
        kmeans=KMeans.fit(df)
        distance_list.append(kmeans.inertia_)
    plt.plot(K,distance_list,'bx-')
```

When I use this function, `df['']` causes error while `df[['']]` doesn’t. I don’t know the reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between df\[x\], df\[\[x\]\], df\['x'\] , df\[\['x'\]\] and df.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50302180/difference-between-dfx-dfx-dfx-dfx-and-df-x)

Answer (score 2):

Difference:

- `df['a']` gives a `Series` object, which is one column, example:

  ```
  >>> df['a']
  0    1
  1    2
  2    3
  Name: a, dtype: int64
  >>>
  ```
- `df[['a']]` selects multiple columns, but in this case only one column is inside the list, therefore the `DataFrame` type is retained:

  ```
  >>> df[['a']]
     a
  0  1
  1  2
  2  3
  >>>
  ```

Comment: Ok, got it. If print Series, it won’t show the column name, while the Dataframe will print the column value, so I can judge whether it is df or Series by this, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

When you write `df["]` you are basically accessing a set of number values, but when you use `df[["]]` you are getting a `DataFrame` object which is compatible with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Returns different type :

```
type(df['a'])
Out[1]: pandas.core.series.Series

type(df[['a']])
Out[2]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```